# Alternative for useDispatch hook of react-redux for Class Component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, design-patterns, redux

`react-redux` library has come up with `useDispatch`, which being a hook can only be used in function component.

```
import React from 'react';
import {useDispatch} from 'react-redux';
import {action} from './actions';

const funComp = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const performAction = () => { dispatch(action()) }
  return <button onClick={performAction}> Dispatch Action </button>
}
```

This simplifies a lot of boiler-plate code for functional component, is there something similar which we can use in class component?

Answer (score 1):

`react-redux` library came with latest `useDispatch` hook using which we can directly dispatch actions from a functional component
react community as a whole seems to encourage this pattern of directly dispatching actions from dispatch variable instead of importing those dispatchers as props on the function component, with the help of `mapDispatchToProps`
We can achieve similar functionality for class component by importing the store and dispatching actions with its dispatch function, and it's `no-brainer` since useDispatch hook internally does the same thing.
 so in a class component same can be achieved like this
**An alternative to useDispatch hook for class component**

```
import React from "react";
import { incrementAction } from "./actions";
import store from "./store";

export class StoreFriend extends React.Component {
  handleStoreIncrement = () => {
    store.dispatch(incrementAction());    // <--- this is the trick. 
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleStoreIncrement}>store increment</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Hacky Bonus: narrow use case alternative of useSelector for class component**
This is only applicable in case the component is aware when the value it requires from redux store is going to update
See the hacky solution below

```
export class StoreFriend extends React.PureComponent {
  
  handleStoreIncrement = () => {
    store.dispatch(incrementAction());
    this.forceUpdate(); // <---This is the hack, everytime class component dispatches the action, it should be forcefully re-rendered to get new value from store
  };
  render() {
    const s = store.getState().value;
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Comp shows store value --> {s}</p>
        <button onClick={this.handleStoreIncrement}>store increment</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

code sandbox link https://codesandbox.io/s/reactredux-qp05m?file=/Page.js

Comment: [**DO NOT** directly import the store into components!](https://redux.js.org/faq/store-setup#can-or-should-i-create-multiple-stores-can-i-import-my-store-directly-and-use-it-in-components-myself).  This is never a good idea.

Comment: please give to the point answer, why it's not a good idea!
useDispatch hook under the hood does the same!

Comment: Because there's a major difference between injecting the store via context at runtime, and having a hardcoded import that ties all your code to that exact store instance (per the FAQ entry).

Comment: If you create a store instance and export it from a module, it will become a singleton. This means it will be harder to isolate a Redux app as a component of a larger app, if this is ever necessary, or to enable server rendering, because on the server you want to create separate store instances for every request.

--- for simple use cases it is ok, neither I am doing SSR, nor my app is to be separated from the app,

Comment: for an app with single redux store, there is no further caveat with calling dispatch directly

Comment: Importing the store directly also makes testing components a lot harder.  Point is, it's a pattern we strictly discourage.

Comment: At this point, people are moving towards cypress ---- which offers two unit testing + e2e testing, I am doing both, there is no difficulty introduced.

---- I am again making the point, that we are simply uncovering the dispatch which was hidden under the hood of library

Answer (score 1):

Class components should use [the React-Redux `connect` API](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect) to interact with the store:

```js
import React from 'react';
import {useDispatch} from 'react-redux';
import {action} from './actions';

const mapState = state => {
  return {
    todos: state.todos
  }
};

const mapDispatch = {action};

class MyClassComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const {todos} = this.props; // use to render something
    return <button onClick={this.props.action}> Dispatch Action </button>
  }
}

export default connect(mapState, mapDispatch)(MyClassComponent);
```